# Telerik RadChart labeling and positioning

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, telerik, radchart

I'm new to Telerik Chart controls and I have some minor problems:

[image: My chart]
(1) I want to set the (1, 2, 3, 4) in the horizontal axis into ("a", "b", "c", "d")
(2) The legend stays at the top of the chart

Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[(1) I want to set the (1, 2, 3, 4) in the horizontal axis into ("a", "b", "c", "d")](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radchart-how-to-add-axis-labels-programmatically.html)

(2) Use the Legend section under the chart wizard to adjust the location of your legend:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<Legend><Appearance Dimensions-Margins="17.6%, 3%, 1px, 1px" Dimensions-Paddings="2px, 8px, 6px, 3px" Position-AlignedPosition="TopRight"><ItemTextAppearance TextProperties-Color="102, 102, 102"></ItemTextAppearance><FillStyle MainColor="216, 222, 227"></FillStyle><Border Color="160, 170, 182" /></Appearance></Legend>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)