# I want to disable the legend in Telerik radchart?

Tags: c#, telerik

how can i disable the legend in the telerik Radchart? This legend is at the left side of the chart.
I want to disable it, because it takes to much place, and on my page  its obviously that the chart is about an selected item.

Comment: I tell you straight- forward that improve your question or delete it immediately. Otherwise, be ready to accept a number of downvotes here. No one is going to see such a question on this site.

Comment: @Lion,  Its a straightforward question, its easy to understand, for people who are familair with Telerik!

Comment: Yes maybe. I'm actually not the opponent of your question but answering this question requires some practical code that you should have already tried. so that you can get your desired answer that actually you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the screenshot on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8245602/232593) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237191/telerik-radchart-labeling-and-positioning), you'll see there is a `Legend -> Visible` check box in the RadChart wizard.

Just uncheck it.

Comment: How do i go to the radchart wizard. I allready have the chart in my project.

Comment: Not sure.  When I was using rad controls I didn't even know these wizards existed, lol.  But here's an easy way to solve this: Create *another* chart with the legend invisible, and inspect the generated code to figure out what property got changed.  Once you figure this out, apply the same change to your existing code.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/chart/understandingwizard.html - "You can invoke the chart wizard from the RadChart Smart Tag, from the context menu that appears when you right-click RadChart and from the link at the bottom of the properties window."

Comment: @Letoir: That sentence was a list of three options.  Try right clicking the rad chart.  or go to it from the link at the bottom of the properties window (probably when you have the cursor/carrot in the middle of the tag in your html)

Comment: @Letoir: Smart tag - http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/chart/understandingsmarttag.html